# Is it possible to prevent creation of a business object in a C# WinForms dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, user-controls, resources

To create/edit an instance of my business class, say,

```
class Person
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
}
```

I implement a user control that has

```
class PersonControl : UserControl
{
  //...
  public Person Person
  {
    get{...}
    set{...}
  }
}
```

where get and set work with the controls of the PersonControl class.
Then I create a dialog, a Form, and create an instance of the PersonControl class, `_ctrlPerson` in it. In the dialog class I have then

```
  public Person Person
  {
    get{return this._ctrlPerson.Person;}
    set{this._ctrlPerson.Person = value;}
  }
```

Annoyingly, VisualStudio creates an instance of the business class Person in the resources, fills it with some values and initializes the controls of the user control with its values. These values are often null or otherwise senseless, so that the designer view does not show up, along with other side effects.

Is such behavior known? How can I prevent VS from creating parasitical instances?

I am using VD 2017 Enterprise.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you experience to go wrong?

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg I can try, but the situation where it happens is within a production project, so I cannot just copy the code fragment. I will try to build a minimum working example.